# Could not Open Database - SQLite React Native

Tags: react-native, sqlite

I have a React Native app which opens connection with local database. The database is placed inside the assets/www folder called OA-DB.db.
This is the const to open the database connection:

```
const db = openDatabase({  name: 'OA-DB.db',  createFromLocation: 1,}, () => console.log('Connected'), (error) => console.log('Error:' + error));
```

This connection is working well on Android 11, Android 13, Android 14 devices. Except one specific device an Android tablet with Android 13 and Samsung One Ui 5.1, that returns Error while tries to open the connection:Error: Could not open database.
I've tried a lot of things, changed the createFromLocation to 1, disabled the Work account, because with the work account on, it doesn't allow to see files on Android Studio.
So now I can see the installation folders and files with Android Studio, and I can see the database folder and inside of it the database file.
Can anyone give me some guidance on this?

### Updates

I've tried some more things, I'm sure the database is present at the folder, the name of the database is correct at the connection, so  indicates that the file is being properly bundled with the app during installation.
I have this app installed on many devices, but the error only occurs on this specific.

### Update 2

Now I've tried another work around, copy the database to another folder inside the device, using the react-native-fs, I was able to copy the database to other folder, but still not able to connect with the database at this device.

function to Copy the Database

```
async function copyDatabaseIfNeeded(){
  const dbPath = '/storage/emulated/0/Documents/'+`${dbName}`;
  console.log('dbPath:'+dbPath);
  console.log('dbLocation:'+dbLocation);
  const dbExists = await RNFS.exists(dbPath);
  if (!dbExists) {
    try {
      // Check if external storage permission is granted (only for Android)
      if (Platform.OS === 'android') {
        const granted = await requestExternalStoragePermission();
        if (!granted) {
          console.error('Storage permission not granted.');
          return;
        }
      }
      // Construct the correct source path for the asset
      const sourcePath = Platform.OS === 'android' ? 'www/onlineaudits_new.db' : dbName;      
      await RNFS.copyFileAssets(sourcePath, dbPath);
      console.log('Database copied successfully');
    } catch (error) {
      console.error('Error copying database:', error);
    }
  }
}
```

**Function to Open Connection**

```
// Open the database connection
function openDatabase() {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    SQLite.openDatabase(
      { name: dbName, location: dbLocation },
      (db) => {
        console.log('Database connection opened successfully');
        resolve(db);
      },
      (error) => {
        console.error('Error opening database:', error + dbLocation);
        reject(error);
      }
    );
  });
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried to use another library to connect with the database?

Comment: Not yet, as I said at the beggining of the post, the app is working fine on many other devices, not working only at one specific. Change the lib will be my last try.

Comment: After many tries, I switched to another library now I'm using sqlite2. react-native-sqlite-storage, works well except on this device. Now I will change the imports and adapt the code to the new library.

Comment: Adding example codes and/or library names and links to docs for those libraries would help more people who might get into this same problem and visit here.